# Generalization of determinant formula

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, solution-verification, jacobian

I want to calculate the determinant a matrix given as
$$\det(\mathbf{A}) = \det
 \begin{pmatrix}
 \dfrac{\partial \omega_1}{\partial x_1} & \dfrac{\partial \omega_1}{\partial x_2} & \dfrac{\partial \omega_1}{\partial x_3}\\  
 \dfrac{\partial \omega_2}{\partial x_1} & \dfrac{\partial \omega_2}{\partial x_2} & \dfrac{\partial \omega_2}{\partial x_3}\\ 
 \dfrac{\partial \omega_3}{\partial x_1} & \dfrac{\partial \omega_3}{\partial x_2} & \dfrac{\partial \omega_3}{\partial x_3}  
 \end{pmatrix},
$$
where each entry is of the form 
$$\frac{\partial \omega_{j}}{\partial x_i} = f_{1,j}a_{1,ij} + f_{2,j}a_{2,ij}.$$
Therefore, $\det(\mathbf{A})$ can be written as 
$$\det
\begin{pmatrix}
f_{1,1}a_{1,11} + f_{2,1}a_{2,11} & f_{1,1}a_{1,21} + f_{2,1}a_{2,21} & f_{1,1}a_{1,31} + f_{2,1}a_{2,31}\\
f_{1,2}a_{1,12} + f_{2,2}a_{2,12} & f_{1,2}a_{1,22} + f_{2,2}a_{2,22} & f_{1,2}a_{1,32} + f_{2,2}a_{2,32}\\
f_{1,3}a_{1,13} + f_{2,3}a_{2,13} & f_{1,3}a_{1,23} + f_{2,3}a_{2,23} & f_{1,3}a_{1,33} + f_{2,3}a_{2,33}\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

By means of expansions, collection and rearrangement in MatLab I was able to determine that 
$$ \det(\mathbf{A}) = \sum_{u=1}^2\sum_{v=1}^2\sum_{w=1}^2 f_{u,1}f_{v,2}f_{w,3}g_{uvw}, \text{ where}$$
$$ g_{uvw} = \det
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{u,11} & a_{u,21} & a_{u,31}\\
a_{v,12} & a_{v,22} & a_{v,32}\\
a_{w,13} & a_{w,23} & a_{w,33}\\
\end{pmatrix}. $$

This a fairly neat result, and it appears as if one should be able to derive it without "brute-forcing" the determinant expansion.

Is there an elegant way to derive this result? Can it be generalized to arbitrary $n\times n$ matrices?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @joriki for the observation of the linearity of each row. Following this idea, $\det(\mathbf{A})$ can be written as

\begin{align}
\det(\mathbf{A})&=\det\begin{pmatrix}
f_{1,1}\begin{bmatrix}a_{1,11} & a_{1,21} & a_{1,31} \end{bmatrix} + f_{2,1}\begin{bmatrix}a_{2,11} & a_{2,21} &a_{2,31}\end{bmatrix}\\
f_{1,2}\begin{bmatrix}a_{1,12} & a_{1,22} & a_{1,32} \end{bmatrix} + f_{2,2}\begin{bmatrix}a_{2,12} & a_{2,22} &a_{2,32}\end{bmatrix}\\
f_{1,3}\begin{bmatrix}a_{1,13} & a_{1,23} & a_{1,33} \end{bmatrix} + f_{2,3}\begin{bmatrix}a_{2,13} & a_{2,23} &a_{2,33}\end{bmatrix}
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=  \sum_{u=1}^2\sum_{v=1}^2\sum_{w=1}^2 \det\begin{pmatrix}
f_{u,1}\begin{bmatrix}a_{u,11} & a_{u,21} & a_{u,31} \end{bmatrix} \\
f_{v,2}\begin{bmatrix}a_{v,12} & a_{v,22} & a_{v,32} \end{bmatrix} \\
f_{w,3}\begin{bmatrix}a_{w,13} & a_{w,23} & a_{w,33} \end{bmatrix} 
\end{pmatrix} \\
&=  \sum_{u=1}^2\sum_{v=1}^2\sum_{w=1}^2 f_{u,1} f_{v,2}f_{w,3}\det\begin{pmatrix}
a_{u,11} & a_{u,21} & a_{u,31} \\
a_{v,12} & a_{v,22} & a_{v,32}  \\
a_{w,13} & a_{w,23} & a_{w,33} 
\end{pmatrix}.\end{align}

This is the result I initially achieved by numerical means.

Comment: Even just from dimensional considerations, you must mean $\det(\mathbf A)$ where you wrote $\det(\mathbf A^{-1})$.

Comment: You are right, that was a typo. Thanks, I fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the rows is a linear combination of two row vectors. This is just the linearity of the determinant applied to the three rows.

Comment: Thanks, this is it! I edited the explicit proof into the original question.